# Into @include Breakpoint not can insert @extend or other @include in Sass

Tags: sass, frontend, compass-sass

I had to take a project that had begun in this project using Sass and the extension of breakpoints ([breakpoint-sass.com](http://breakpoint-sass.com)), I found the following code to compile it gave me error:

```
.main-menu {
  @include breakpoint(930px) {
    @extend %layout-adaptive;
    // Error Gulp
  }
}
```

The extend exists, I tried it in different ways, the error also happens to include breakpoint by inserting another breakpoint.

Any idea if there alternative to this solution?

[image]

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Comment: I've added a screenshot